# Latest kernel update (4.8.0-39-generic) for 16.04.2 ... crashing after login?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, crash

Just installed the new hardware enablement stack yesterday; all fine.

Today, kernel update to 4.8.0-39-generic ... and after reboot and entering my login password ... nothing. Just my desktop; no mouse pointer; full hang; I have to press the power button to switch of the machine in the end.

Any idea anybody?

Comment: Did you install any proprietary video drivers?

Comment: And you can always boot with an old kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 I would have not been writing this question if I didn't know how to boot an older kernel ... and no; since 16.04 I am going with the "built in stuff"; no longer using nvidia drivers.

Comment: So can you boot OK with an old kernel?

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear: yes. I am using that older kernel right now!

Comment: OK, and what is the video adapter? It looks like a bug, that should be reported.

Comment: I have a Lenovo w530 here, some nvidia graphics hardware ... sometimes these things get updated easily; if not, I will consider writing a defect.

Comment: Which Nvidia is there?

Comment: Same problem here. After updating to the latest kernel (ubuntu 16.04.2), kernel panics few seconds after the login screen shows up. Booting with the old kernel works OK. In my case, it seems like it's an ASUS motherboard issue. Try to press CTRL+ALT+F1 right when the the login screen shows up, and wait for the kernel to panic, to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Update: turns out the root cause for the crash is a problem with Symantec Antivirus. My company forces us to run that; and although its version 1.0.14.13 compiles with 4.8.39 ... it causes that crash upon login.

At least for me that means that I have to wait updates from symantec here.